# How edit BundleConfig.json in xamarin.android app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

I am writing a Xamarin.Android application using Visual Studio 2022. Unfortunately, the .abb package is required for new applications. This is where the problem with changing the language in the application begins. I am using ContextWrapper to change the language. I have read for the language to work properly in the application, I have to add this code to the BundleConfig.json file:

```
android {
bundle {
    language {
    // Specifies that the app bundle should not support
    // configuration APKs for language resources. These
    // resources are instead packaged with each base and
    // dynamic feature APK.
    enableSplit = false
    }
   }
  }
```

Unfortunately, I have nowhere found on the internet how to edit this file and where to find it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in .NET localization framework to set languages in your app,
The built-in mechanism for localizing .NET applications uses RESX files and the classes in the System.Resources and System.Globalization namespaces. The RESX files containing translated strings are embedded in the Xamarin.Forms assembly, along with a compiler-generated class that provides strongly-typed access to the translations. The translated text can then be retrieved in code.

You can refer to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows

Comment: I've already come across resx files in UWP. I thought they didn't work in Xamarin.Android applications. I still have a question. Does AppResources.resx have to be placed in the region's values directory or it just has to be in the Resources directory?

Comment: You could refer to the sample project https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/UsingResxLocalization/UsingResxLocalization/UsingResxLocalization