# using resx in xaml in the application xamarin.android app

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

Is it possible to use a string resource in xaml from the resx file in xamarin.android? (like @ string / stringResource) There are a lot of examples for xamarin.forms and unfortunately I can't find anything for xamarin.android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xamarin.Forms, you could use the `Resx files`. You create the files for the Forms project. I take the `Localization` for reference.

But if you want to do something like resx on Android, you need to use the `Strings.xml` file like what you said `@string`. On Android platform, it has different implementation. Create a `Strings.xml` file of value folder inside Resource folder.

Xamarin.Forms:

- For more details about the Xamarin.Forms String and Image
  Localization, please check the link.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows#create-resx-files
- You could download the sample from the link below.        https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/usingresxlocalization/

Xamarin.Android:

- For more details about Android Localization, you could refer to the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/localization

Comment: The problem is that I am struggling with the problem of changing the language in the application in the new .abb package. @string only works in the installed language and it is not possible to change it. In the post below they advised me to switch to resx files which also work in xamarin.android. The problem is, I can't use them in xaml only in code, and that's a problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70584748/how-edit-bundleconfig-json-in-xamarin-android-app/70588285?noredirect=1#comment124836236_70588285

Comment: You could create the Xamarin.Forms project to use the resx files and set the Android as startup project. This would make the resx files work for Android platform. Xamarin.Forms is a cross-platform UI toolkit that allows developers to efficiently create native user interface layouts that can be shared across iOS, Android, and Universal Windows Platform apps. You could create a Xamarin.Forms project instead of Xamarin.Android project.